# file input MVC 3 Client-side validation for required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, file-io, unobtrusive-javascript

Simple question... Is it possible to use client side MVC 3 validation on inputs of type file?

To explain: MVC 3 uses its model validation with IClientValidatable and unobtrusive javascript to allow you to write validation on the server side and have it render the client side using jquery validate using Microsoft's plugins. To make a property required you add the attribute below

```
[Required]
public HttpPostedFileBase CvFile {get; set;}
```

As long as client side val and unobtrusive javascript is on in the config this should all fire on the client.

However `HttpPostedFileBase` (i.e. `<input type="file" name="Model.CvFile" />)` will not run required on the client side.

Any ideas how this can be achieved keeping the relationship with the server side validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: A `HttpPostedFileBase` renders "file" input type which is a security issue and, AFAIK, is not scriptable. There's no support for this "out of the box".

Edit: this seems to be a very popular topic online.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, rendering the control and building it is not a problem (code can be provided if you like). However making client side validation which is tied into is the problem. any ideas?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1566760/4033836.aspx has a great discussion on file upload validation. From here I would create a custom validator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662923/asp-net-mvc3-custom-validation-attribute-client-side-broken or http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html . They might look complicated, but are well worth understanding.

Answer (score 28):

You need to add it manually:

```
<input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="please select a file" name="file" />
@Html.ValidationMessage("file")
```