# asp mvc file upload (with validation)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload

[image: My model:]

[image: My controller:]

[image: Before submit (file is selected)]

[image: After submit (file is cleared)]

As you can see my model (TestFileUploadModel) and my controller action (FileUpload)

-> 3th screen before i submit: file is selected
-> 4th screen after i submit: name field is required, but file is cleared..

Anyone who was an idea how to solve this? (or a workaround?)

Comment: Validate client-side. On a round-trip to the server, the file cannot be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment by user bzlm you can check with JQuery if the file has value and prevent the submit of the form.

You can attach a function at the submit of your form and do this check

```
if ($("#MyInputFileField").val()) { 
  //do your things
}
else
{
  //PreventDefault and show error message
}
```

EDIT:
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633092/input-type-file-mvc-3-client-side-validation-for-required/5634767#5634767) for an answer that should be similar to your question

for an example using jquery validation plugin check [this](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html)

Comment: This is built into ASP.NET MVC. No need to re-invent the wheel. :)

Comment: AFAIK the MVC doesn't validate the input type upload with an Html helper. At least not without the jquery.validation plugin.

Comment: this looks exactly what i need! But do you have some code example? because i can't figure out how it works..

Comment: In my update, the second link I posted, point to a demo with jquery validation. If you mean how to intercept the form post look here http://api.jquery.com/submit/